# When to use getActiviy() when to use View to initialize objects in Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have everything working.  I would like to know why and how it's working.

I wanted to retain my setting on a textView using Bundle SavedInstanceState.  in the fragment going from portrait to landscape data retained and reset all is well; however, when going back to portrait....crash NPE on TextView object !  after some Logging I noticed the TVobject not being set on going back to Portrait.  My workaround is below...can someone please help me understand what is going on under the hood.  Thanks.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle sis) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.myhistfrag_b, container, false);


    text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvNewD);
    // work around reset with v not getActivity() ///  why ?
    if(text==null){
        text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNewD);
    }


    if( sis != null ) {
        Log.e("myLog me", sis.get("data").toString());
        Log.d("myLog me 2", text.toString());
    text.setText(sis.get("data").toString());


    }


    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're creating the `Fragment`'s `View` in `onCreateView()`. It's not yet attached to the `Activity`, so using the `Activity` to search for the view will always fail. Use `onCreateView()` simply to *create* the `Fragment`'s `View`, and use `onViewCreated()` to assign your `View` references using the `View` provided in the method (or at that point you can use `getView()`). For example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myhistfrag_b, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedState) {
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNewD);

    if (savedState != null) {
        text.setText(sis.getString("data"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but, I just replaced my code with yours with no luck.  The Fragment does not retain the TextView data.  I will review the Activity\Fragment life cycle regardless.  Thx.